# run time bind error in socket server program

Tags: c, sockets

server program in c using socket :

```
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<netinet/in.h>
    #include<arpa/inet.h>  
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #define MYPORT 4444
    #define BACKLOG 100
    #define MAXBUFSIZE 100

    int main(void)
    {
        int sockfd,newfd,sin_size,i,count;
        struct sockaddr_in my_addr,their_addr; 
        char request[MAXBUFSIZE] = "This is the servers request";
        char buf[100];

        /*Create Socket */
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        printf("\nSocket created");

        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("10.228.37.9");

        /*Bind Socket*/
        i=bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if(i<0)
        {
            printf("\nBind Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nBind socket");
        }

        /*Listen */
        listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) ;
        if( listen(sockfd, BACKLOG)==-1)
        {
            printf("\nError in listening");
         }
        else
            printf("Listened Successfully");

        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        /*Accept*/
        newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,&sin_size);

        /*Receive from Client*/
        count = recv(newfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (count < 0) 
        {
            printf("recv error");
            exit(1);
        }
        buf[count]='\0';
        printf("\nReceived: %s",buf);
        printf("\nSuccessful");

        /*Send to Client*/ 
        if (send(newfd, request, (int)strlen(request), 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("send error");
            exit(1);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

this is a server program in c using socket,
there is no compilation error but in run time the program should wait for the client but it showing bind error. 
run time bind error in socket server program

Comment: Hint: `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: Why are you trying to bind to a specific IP address? Usually we bind to INADDR_ANY to accept all connections...

Comment: @Medinoc There is nothing wrong with binding to a specific IP address though.  My money's on `EADDRINUSE`.

Comment: Bind Erroran error: Address already in use

Comment: OK.  Add error reporting code **everywhere** that can go wrong and then the solutions are:  1) kill the process using that port.  2) wait a bit for the O/S to forget about the process that was using that port.  3) Use the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option for the bind socket.

Comment: got an answer  i changed the ip and its working now.i will kill that process and compile it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix "Address already in use"
set the FLAG `SO_REUSEADDR` by calling `setsocketopt`

This is just a small demonstration how to reuse port

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
int main(){

//create a new socket stream
int sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock_fd == -1){
   printf("Socket Error %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
int reuse;
if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) == -1){
 printf("Reuse port Error : %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
// configure the socket
struct sockaddr_in sock_addr;
 //bind to port 4500
sock_addr.sin_port = (in_port_t) htons(4500);
sock_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
// bind the socket to given port
if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr)) == -1){
  printf("Bind Error %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

//listner to only 2 clients
 listen(sock_fd, 2);
// keep the connection running
 while(1){

 struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;

   // appect a connection from client
    unsigned int addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
   int conn_fd = appect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_size);

  char *msg = "Hello World";

  send(conn_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
  close(conn_fd);
 } 
}
```

Comment: can you justify your answer

Comment: Yes I can.  The OP had no clue *why* `bind()` was failing until he added `strerror(errno)` and you are continuing that problem with the code you have provided.

Comment: hey i have updated my answer even there is problem with this then tell me and its untested.

Comment: Looking better, however you need to `exit(1)` whenever there's an error.

Comment: yeah you are right, however we also need to close the socket descriptor (if there is sending or receiving error,, so on) instead of depending on `printf` to show error message.

Comment: Yes indeed.  The structure is poor.